# Simulating a spinner for progress in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am currently learning how to make scripts a bit more verbose. The below code shows a spinner. However, I am having difficulties modifying this spinner to have the words such as 'Downloading'. I want both the words and spinner to appear beside each other. I am not asking how to implement spinner for progress but how to concatenate with words. How could achieve this goal?

```
sp='/-\|'
sc=0
spin() {
   printf "\b${sp:sc++:1}"
   ((sc==${#sp})) && sc=0
}
endspin() {
   printf "\r%s\n" "$@"
}

until work_done; do
   spin
   some_work ...
done
endspin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I admire the DIY spirit of Ed and Jakuje I also like to reuse other folks code.  If you'd rather recycle than recreate consider [Louis Marascio's spinner](http://fitnr.com/showing-a-bash-spinner.html).  I put his `spinner()` function into my shell library and it is easy to use:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

. lib.sh
run_10s &
echo -n wait
spinner $!
echo -e "\rdone"
```

displays

```bash
$ ./test_lib
wait [/]
```

for 10 seconds with the spinner spinning and then it clears that line left containing `wait` with the `\r` and you are left with just

```bash
$ ./test_lib
done
```

on the screen.

Comment: Great! I rather go with this approach. However, I am calling spinner function inside a while loop. It initially work spins as intended for two seconds and then it shows "waitwaitwaitwaitwaitwaitwaitwaitwaitwaitwait..." . How can I fix that?

Comment: http://fitnr.com/showing-a-bash-spinner.html link looks dead

Answer (score 7):

You can do so like this

```
sp='/-\|'
sc=0
spin() {
   printf "\r${sp:sc++:1} $1"
   ((sc==${#sp})) && sc=0
}
endspin() {
   printf "\r%s\n" "$@"
}
work_done() {
   false
}
some_work() {
   sleep 1
}

until work_done; do
   spin "Downloading"
   some_work ...
done
endspin
```

Comment: could the words "Downloading" come before the spinner?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student Use `printf "\r$1 ${sp:sc++:1}"` instead in the `spin` function for that I believe.

Comment: When the word of the spin is long `spin "Downloading that thing ok"` then we we stop it, `endspin "Sucess"`, it will have the output when spin is end: "Successading that thing ok"

Comment: spin:1: bad substitution